# Select custom field using laravel orm

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, orm

I have one table where i need to fetch all records along with one custom field too
i.e

```
SELECT
      name,
      code_no,
      '0001' as batch_id // this is cutome field
FROM 
mytable //batch_id is cutom filed
```

i tried

```
MyTable::select('name','code_no','00101 as batch_id')->get();
```

Any ideas please??

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
MyTable::select('*', DB::raw('"0001" as `batch_id`'))->get();
```

It will select all columns form your model table as well as 0001 as batch_id.
DB::raw makes sure the param is applied "as is" without trying to "convert" 0001 into column name.